# bar chart configuration in nvd

Tags: jquery, graph, integer

I am trying to show a graph by making use of nvd plugin.
It is showing proper data but though I am sending integer data, it showing float data in x axis with 2 decimal places and when I mouse over then it is showing float with one decimal place.
My code is like:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
   var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
       .x(function(d) { return d.label })
       .y(function(d) { return d.value })
       .staggerLabels(true)
       .tooltips(false)
       .showValues(true)

   d3.select('#chart svg')
       .datum(exampleData())
     .transition().duration(500)
       .call(chart);

   nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

   return chart;
 });

 function exampleData() {
  return  [ 
     {
       key: "Cumulative Return",
       values: [
         { 
           "label" : "CDS / Options" ,
           "value" : 29
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Cash" , 
           "value" : 0
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Corporate Bonds" , 
           "value" : 32
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Equity" , 
           "value" : 196
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Index Futures" ,
           "value" : 0
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Options" , 
           "value" : 98
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Preferred" , 
           "value" : 13
         } , 
         { 
           "label" : "Not Available" , 
           "value" : 5
         }
       ]
     }
   ];
 }
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.